# How to get result of ( used struct:codable) parsing string in a pickerview

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I have hit the API and got the response successfully. I used codable here for parsing.1.But could not get a particular value. id?
                2. The picker is called first and not loaded with the strings which we parsed.

Parsing from codable is littly sticky. How to get the array content inside it , like the id value into it.
     codable part: 
    struct Reasons : Codable{
      let reason_and_whom_meet : both?
    }

```
struct both :Codable{
   let reason_list : [reasonlist]?
   let whom_meet : [nameList]?
}

struct reasonlist :Codable{
  let id: Int?    //This "id" i couldnt access. 
  let reason : String?
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

  case reason
  case id
  }
}

struct nameList :Codable{
    let name : String?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case name
    }
}
```

The codable struct I did by the structure of json which i receive. Should I change the structure of the struct I have used.

If you want the json value also I can provide, but the struct is exact hierarchy of json.

Code Part:

```
do {
    let gotData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Reasons.self, from: data!)
    let persons = gotData.reason_and_whom_meet?.whom_meet

    self.wtmArray.add(persons)
    print(self.wtmArray)

    let reasons = gotData.reason_and_whom_meet?.reason_list
    self.reasonArray.add(reasons)
    print(self.reasonArray)

    let reasonID = gotData.reason_and_whom_meet?.reason_list![self.reasonID]
    print(reasons)
} catch let err {
    print("Error", err)
}
```

Also the picker delegate methods are called first but the response is empty at that time. How to resolve this? My picker shows empty. And the response are like :

```
"GoogleClassroomPoC.nameList(name: Optional(\"Teacher\"))"
```

But I need that Teacher and Principal alone in my array. Should I convert that to any format or can we show it directly in pickerview.

I am fighting  with this parsing, Please help!

Comment: Please add the JSON you are parsing and the code you are using for picker.

Comment: @PGDev. But how can get id if its in array.?

Comment: You can get id for each array element like this: `self.data?.reason_list?[row].id`

Comment: { "reason_and_whom_meet": { "reason_list": [{"id": 1,"reason": "Out of turn leave request for my child "},{ "id": 2,"reason": "Teachers related feedback"},{ "id": 3, "reason": "Academics related feedback" }, {"id": 4,
"reason": "Mail id and google class room related" }, {"id": 5,"reason": "Transport Related"}, {"id": 6,"reason": "Child Related"},{ "id": 7 "reason": "Others"}], "whom_meet": [{"id": 1,"name": "Teacher"},{"id": 2,"name": "Principal"} ]}}  This is the json i got. Please format is using formatter. Not allowing to edit in question part.  Still i cant see my pickerview populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a simple code that is similar to your scenario on how to get this working.

**1.** A simple `UIPickerView` with a single component that display `reason` of `reason_list` of `both`.

```
var data: both?

@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.data?.reason_list?.count ?? 0
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return self.data?.reason_list?[row].reason
}
```

Initially, when the `ViewController` is loaded, `data` is `nil` and so the `UIPickerView` doesn't show anything.

**2.** I have created a `UIButton` that loads the `data` and the `UIPickerView` is reloaded. I've used some hardcoded data. You can get this data from your API.

```
@IBAction func loadData(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let jsonString = """
    {
        "reason_list": [
            {"id": 1, "reason": "ABCD"},
            {"id": 2, "reason": "WXYZ"}
        ]
    }
    """

    if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
    {
        self.data = try? JSONDecoder().decode(both.self, from: data)
         DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
               self?.picker.reloadComponent(0) //HERE..!!!
         }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: If i use reloadallcomponents() after the response . It is throwing an error like u should call it from the main thread.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Any UI update must be done on the `main` thread. Use `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: I have added the Json in comments section. @PGDev

Comment: Have you reloaded your content after receiving API response? What exactly do you want to show in `UIPickerView`?

Comment: Here i am facing another issue. I got the separated String : 

whom_meet(name: Optional("Teacher"))  by for in loop     
 from this      

Optional([GoogleClassroomPoC.whom_meet(name: Optional("Teacher")), GoogleClassroomPoC.whom_meet(name: Optional("Principal"))]).            

But i am facing problem while trimming that to get the "Teacher " from that. Because that is not String? So that my array looks like names = ["Teacher", "Principal"]

Comment: Add the updated code that you have used to fetch data and then decode it.

Comment: After decoding only i am getting this value , if i am not wrong? That string has to trimmed ? if it is trimmed then we can easily append that to our array and we can show that array. Sorry for making it deeper.

Comment: Are you talking about Optional?

Comment: Got that . By let gotData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Reasons.self, from: data!)
               
                let persons = gotData.reason_and_whom_meet?.whom_meet
                
                print(persons)
                
                for person in persons!{
                    
                    self.wtmArray.append(person.name!)
                }
                
                print(self.wtmArray)

Now this array gives my exactly like what i want. Thank you for helping how to call from main thread , that actually played well.

Comment: But if i try this to run in device its showing nothing in picker , getting confused??

Comment: Did you set UIPickerView’s delegate and dataSource?

Comment: Yes. It is running in simulator, thats the confusion. While running in device , it shows: index out of range in didselectrow function but content is not shown.

Comment: Add the code of `didselectrow` and check the number of elements in the array that you are using as datasource to `UIPickerView`

Comment: It was port error it seems, because i have passed correct values. Now its fine. I want to contact you, may i get your contact please ?

Comment: You can ask me if you still any issues. Accept and upvote the answer if it worked. Happy Coding... For more on `Codable` you can refer to: https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999

Comment: Hi. I am using Alamofire request , i am facing  a issue that: the delegate methods of table view gets executed first before the alamofire request where i will get the response and store it in the arrays. i have also called the dispatch_async method inside the request, but code fails to reach that.